# What are the parameters of pyplot.subplot?

Tags: matplotlib, deep-learning

Can't understand pyplot.subplot(330+1+i)

```py
# plot first few images
for i in range(9):
    #define subplot
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    # plot raw pixel data
    pyplot.imshow(trainX[i], cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))

# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Note that this is a very old way to use matplotlib.  When working with subplots, it is highly recommended to use `fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=3)` and `for trainX_i, ax in zip(trainX, axs.flatten()): ax.imshow(trainX_i, ...)`.   See https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/

Answer (score 1):

You can view the arguments in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) for `subplot`. The basic arguments are `subplot(nrows, ncols, index)` where `nrows` is the number of rows of plots, `ncols` is the number of columns of plots, and `index` is the plot number when counting across the grid of plots from left to right, top to bottom.

Another way to specify subplots is with a three-digit integer as in your example.

> A 3-digit integer. The digits are interpreted as if given separately as three single-digit integers, i.e. fig.add_subplot(235) is the same as fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 5). Note that this can only be used if there are no more than 9 subplots.

In your example where `i` ranges from 0 to 8, inclusive, the argument for `subplot` will range from 331 to 339. Following to the documentation, your subplots will be over 3 rows and 3 columns with in indices 1 to 9.

Comment: yeah, that I knew but in the code its + sign inside the function.can you please explain what's the + sign is for
ty

Comment: It is explained in the documentation. I will edit my answer with the relevant section quoted.